# Avoid defined but not used on static const class

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

This seems like a trivial thing, but I'm not an expert in C++, and I haven't found a good solution to this online as of yet.  I'm suspecting I'm missing some basic coding construct that might solve this issue.  I have the following definition in one of my main header files:

```
static const Foo   INVALID_FOO = {};
```

where `Foo` is a POD class (it doesn't have constructors, as it's used in a union in a C++03 project).   This seems fine, except for sources which include the header but don't use `INVALID_FOO`, I'm getting the warning:

```
 error: 'Foo::INVALID_FOO' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
```

I've tried removing the `static` but then I get duplicate definitions.   I could make this a forward declaration, and define it in a .c file, but then the compiler would need to access it through a reference and would not be able to make any optimizations.   I'd also like to not disable the `-Wall` compiler flag.  I'm wondering if there's a good way to do this?

Comment: I wonder if the `inline`ing of C++17 could help?

Comment: Do you *want* `INVALID_FOO` to be defined in each and every [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))? Why not simply *declare* it in the header file, and have the definition in a source file (where it's actually used)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I nearly pressed "post your answer" on an answer based on exactly that, but I have the impression the OP is aware of that.

Comment: @Bathsheba Reading the question a little more I think so too.

Comment: Since you use GCC you could use pragmas to disable the warning just for the definition, and then restore the defaults after it.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- I'm not following your first comment.  Yes, I could declare it and then define it in a c file, but this is for embedded, so it would be good if the compiler to could expand `ifeq (fooInst == INVALID_FOO)` to a couple of `bnz` instructions instead of doing loads and compares all over the place.  I'll likely going to go with the pragmas solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the GCC warning like this:

```
static const Foo INVALID_FOO __attribute__ ((unused)) = {};
```

Note that `unused` is correct here, all it does is that it suppresses the warning (and it's still fine to reference the identifier).  There is also a `used` attribute which suppresses the warning *and* tells GCC to emit the definition in the object file even if the compiler does not see a reference to it in the source code—in most cases, this results in unnecessary code bloat.

Comment: Small correction -- the `__attribute__((unused))` has to come before the `=`, otherwise I get a compile error (`expected , or ; before '__attribute__'`).   Might be a gcc version thing...

Comment: With C++17 could also use the standard `[[maybe_unused]]` [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) (or `[[gnu::unused]]` as GCC doesn't recognize `maybe_unused` yet).

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the warning portably using `static_cast<void>(INVALID_FOO);` statement.

Also note that `static const` at global and namespace scope is a bit of tautology - `const` makes it `static`, so that `static` is superfluous.